# Timing? A parameter? Check boxes become disabled on Gridview pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I'm probably missing something simple and obvious.

I have an ASP.Net page, C# code behind, and on this page is a gridview of Jobs that need to have billing directives imported.  Project leads tell the billing department to Bill, Hold, or Write Off the hours.  Each Job will have multiple rows of hours.  Say Job 123456 has 20 people working on it, so there may be 20 individual timesheet directives to deal with.  In my gridview, I have a checkbox for the billing clerk to check if she wants to import those directives, but I wait to enable the checkbox until ALL of the rows have a directive so she will import one entire job.  So, in the example above, for job 123456, if I have 19 directives for 20 employees, the checkbox is disabled and the job cannot be imported until the 20th directive comes through.

In its current state, there are about 50 jobs on three pages in this gridview.  When it loads, I see the first page with 18 disabled checkboxes and two enabled.  If I flip to page two, and then back to page one, those two jobs are disabled.

When I set a breakpoint and step through the "set checkbox" code, I note that the values being evaluated for enabling/disabling the checkbox are from the page I am leaving, rather than the page I'm going to.  How do I correct my error?

Here is how the call is made:

```
BindImportBIsGridView();
SetCheckBoxByWBS1();
```

Here is the CheckBox code:

```
protected void SetCheckBoxByWBS1()
{
    // Here we find all the WBS1s that have ALL of their PKeys in the BillingDirectives table.
    //      We don't want to import partial Jobs.  Thus we wait (disable checkbox) until ALL the PKeys for a given job are sent from IPCS.
    //      Once we have all PKeys, we enable the checkboxes for that WBS1.
    //      This code will execute every time the Gridview is populated.
    SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InterfaceDev"].ConnectionString);
    string myCountCommandText = "select distinct T1.WBS1 from InterfaceDev..BillingDirectiveNeeded T1 where exists (select 1 from InterfaceDev..BillingDirectives T2 where T2.PKey = T1.PKey)";
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myCountCommandText, myConn);
    myConn.Open();
    SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        string myStringValue = myReader["WBS1"].ToString();

        foreach (GridViewRow myRow in ImportBIsGridView.Rows)
        {

            Label myLabel = (Label)myRow.FindControl("JobLabel");
            if (myLabel.Text == myStringValue)
            {
                CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)myRow.FindControl("SelectedCheckBox");
                myCheckBox.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    myConn.Close();
    myCommand.Dispose();
}
```

And here is the start of the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ImportBIsGridView" 
    runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="True" 
    AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#FFFFCC" 
    ShowFooter="True" 
    DataKeyNames="WBS1" 
    BackColor="White" 
    HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" 
    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#546E96" 
    FooterStyle-BackColor="#C3CFDD" 
    PageSize="20" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    EnableViewState="False"
    OnPageIndexChanging="ImportBIsGridView_PageIndexChanging"
    Font-Size="Small"
    >
```

Adding code per Martin's request.  It looks like I need to call the SetCheckBox code here too??

```
protected void ImportBIsGridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    ImportBIsGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    ImportBIsGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that runs when you change PageIndex

Comment: Yes, Martin.  I'll do that now.

Comment: Sweetness Martin!  That was exactly what I needed to do.  The checkboxes are now properly enabled/disabled on each page, and that state is retained when moving between the pages!